# xmodmap Remap Left Mouse to Right Mouse

Tags: mouse, xmodmap

What I've tried:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 3"
xmodmap -e "LeftMouse = RightMouse"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***`LeftMouse`*** and ***`RightMouse`*** probably are not actually keycodes.  You can see this using **`"xmodmap -pk"`** to print the table of known/assigned keycodes.